# Что означают синие кружочки слева от кода в редакторе Delphi?

Tags: delphi, ide

Что означают синие кружочки слева от кода в редакторе Delphi? Они появляются после запуска проекта. Что они делают?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Они означают какой кусочек кода скомпилирован и выполнен.
Это нормальное поведение, а вот при возникновении ошибки код остановится и будет кружочек красным :)

Comment: они означают возможность отладки модуля. т.е. на эти строки можно поставить точку останова (breakpoint).

Comment: Да вы правы, при компиляции они становятся зелеными.